# Access ODBC connection made on another PC?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-xp, odbc

I have made an ODBC connection on a Windows XP machine.

I have another Windows 8 machine on the same network. I want to access that ODBC connection on XP from the Windows 8 machine without having to install ODBC drivers on the Windows 8 machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes;  Of course it is;  Just configure the database server to allow remote connection, by default, in most cases only localhost is allowed.

Comment: The ODBC drivers for my database server (AcuCobol) are not compatible with Windows 8 so I can only install them on Win XP. I have a MS Access db on Xp machine which uses an ODBC connection to get data from AcuCobol server. Are you saying I can share this ODBC connection on XP machine to 8 machine?

Comment: I missed the part where you said you wanted to do this without install ODBC drivers, yeah you can't do that, I thought you were asking if you connect to a remote database server using an ODBC connection. Hence the title (*Access ODBC connection made on another PC?*).

Comment: @Kashif How are you using that ODBC connection/driver? AFAIK ODBC connection forwarding - as you describe it - is impossible.